# How to pass Json Request body from one HttpRequest as a value in the next http request?

Tags: rest, jmeter, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-5.0

I'm trying to capture payload (in JSON) created from an HTTP request and pass it as a value to the next API request.

Step1: Create Http Request Payload. Sample Below:

```
{  
   "fdCustomerId":"${cuid}",
   "account":{  
      "type":"CREDIT",
      "credit":{  
         "cardNumber":"ENC_[${Output2}]",
         "nameOnCard":"John Smith",
         "cardType":"${cardtype}",
         "cardSubType": "${cardsubtype}",
         "billingAddress":{  
            "type":"work",
            "country":"US",
            "primary":true
         }
}
```

Step2: Capture the final Payload into a variable using post processes

```
var requestBody = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
vars.put("requestBody", requestBody);
log.info("###########################################Request     Body are:##########" + requestBody);
```

Step3: Pass the `RequestBody` variable as a value to the next HTTP request

```
{ 
 "category": "GBS_ExecMetrics_UCom", 
 "consumed": false, 
 "data": { "Test Case Id": "AB_CMS_006_CC_001_500_", 
         "Account Number": "0001210520779700304", 
         "Primary Card Number": "**${requestBody}**",  
         "Secondary Card Number": "0000377883144114646",  
         "Run Date Time": "03/26/201917:30"}
```

}

When I hit that to the endpoint I get below error message:

> {"Error":"BadRequest: Please provide a valid Json"...

How to convert this to string or include escape characters with a function and pass the request-body?

Answer (score 0):

My bad with the sample request syntax taken in step 1.Above steps worked as-is.

Corrected the syntax as below and was able to pass the json. Thanks.

```
{  
"fdCustomerId":"${cuid}",
```

"account":{
      "type":"CREDIT",
      "credit":{
         "cardNumber":"ENC_[${Output2}]",
         "nameOnCard":"John Smith",
         "cardType":"${cardtype}",
         "cardSubType": "${cardsubtype}",
         "billingAddress":{
            "type":"work",
            "country":"US",
            "primary":true
         }
     }
     }
     }